# How to automate an API to change the URL every hour and append the new data to a csv

Tags: python-3.x, api

I have successfully implemented an API that generates a unique URL to grab data from a database and downloads it into a csv. I am now attempting to automate this API so that it can generate the unique URL every hour and then append the csv file with the new data. I have no idea where to begin to automate this but the working API is pasted below so any help would be truly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime 
from os.path import expanduser 
import urllib.request

def main():
    
    # API parameters
    options = {}
    options["url"] = "https://airnowapi.org/aq/data/"
    options["start_date"] = "2020-01-01"
    options["start_hour_utc"] = "01"
    options["end_date"] = "2020-01-01"
    options["end_hour_utc"] = "05"
    options["parameters"] = "pm25"
    options["bbox"] = "-76,38,-72,42"
    options["data_type"] = "b"
    options["format"] = "text/csv"
    options["ext"] = "csv"
    options["api_key"] = "" #NotIncludedforProtectionOfUniqueAPIkey

    # API request URL
    REQUEST_URL = options["url"] \
                  + "?startdate=" + options["start_date"] \
                  + "t" + options["start_hour_utc"] \
                  + "&enddate=" + options["end_date"] \
                  + "t" + options["end_hour_utc"] \
                  + "&parameters=" + options["parameters"] \
                  + "&bbox=" + options["bbox"] \
                  + "&datatype=" + options["data_type"] \
                  + "&format=" + options["format"] \
                  + "&api_key=" + options["api_key"]

    try:
        # Request AirNowAPI data
        print("Requesting AirNowAPI data...")
        print(REQUEST_URL)

        # User's home directory.
        home_dir = expanduser("E:\SPRING2021\AIRNOWAPI\AIRNOWFILES")
        download_file_name = "AirNowAPI" + datetime.now().strftime("_%Y%M%d%H%M%S." + options["ext"])
        download_file = os.path.join(home_dir, download_file_name)

        # Perform the AirNow API data request    
        api_data = urllib.request.URLopener()
        api_data.retrieve(REQUEST_URL, download_file)

        # Download complete
        print ("Download URL: %s" % REQUEST_URL) 
        print("Download File: %s" % download_file)  

    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable perform AirNowAPI request. %s"  % e) 
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I find most of your code is well documented. There are many ways to automated your task. Here are the steps I would recommend you to do.

1. Create a `Config` file.
2. Try to separate your code from config(All the `options` data). You can even pickle it.
3. Make your code command line executable like `python main.py config.yml`, where you can pass config.file.

   **Checkpoint**: Here your code should be one/multiple file and config is in another file.
4. Use a cronjob or any scheduler to trigger & step 3.

**Shared Variables/Data?**: If you have variables that need to be passed from first execution to another then you can use a static file, where you dump this data and using it for next interation